# Get Created Date of Custom Objects in Visual Force page

Tags: schema

I want to get the created date of all the custom objects present in my Org.

Comment: Can you add more detail and also code of what you have tried so far? If you want to get the CreateDate of every record of a Custom Object you can use: `Select CreatedDate From MyObject__c`

Comment: Are you asking for the createddate of records (data) or the date at which custom objects were created (=deployed or configured) ?  Currently your question epxresses the latter, if that's not the case please edit/update the question.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke Ya I am asking about the created date of custom object.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know and can see **that information is not stored for custom objects**.  The [custom object metadata api documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/index_Left.htm#CSHID=customobject.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Fcustomobject.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp) lists a lot of properties about a custom object, but createddate or any other indication to the time this was either deployed or configurd is not there as far as I can see.